# Should the "initCount" variable be declared "volatile"?

Tags: c, multithreading

```
static int initCount = 0;

int objInit(void)   
{ 

    int i;

    /* Check for reentrancy */

    TaskLock ();
    i = initCount++;
    TaskUnlock ();

    if (i > 0)
        {
        while (!initialized)
            TaskDelay (100);

        return (OK);
        }
    ......
}
```

Should the variable `initCount` be declared `volatile`?

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't need to be `volatile`. However `TaskLock ()` must impose some sort of memory barrier to ensure the operations are carried out in that order, i.e. first lock, then load `initCount`. It's likely your locking primitives already do this.

---

[Volatile: Almost Useless for Multi-Threaded Programming](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming).

Comment: perhaps the initialized variable should be?  Would this be optimized out?

Comment: @JoshPetitt Maybe if it's modified from a signal handler :-? Not sure though. If it's merely modified from another thread `volatile` isn't needed and at the same time not enough.